# Difference between two methods of console input

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to calculate area of a rectangle by accepting input from user with the below code which works fine

```
public void AreaOfRectangle()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Width");
    Width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Length");
    Lenth = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    //Width = 24.5;
    //Lenth = 24.5;
    //double area;
}
```

but if i write the same in below way i am getting incorrect value of area.

```
public void AreaOfRectangle()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Width");
    Width = Console.Read();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Length");
    Lenth = Console.Read();
    //Width = 24.5;
    //Lenth = 24.5;
    //double area;
}
```

Can any one tell me what is the difference between two method logic?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32() will not get you 24.5 You need Convert.ToDouble()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) `Console.Read()` is reading the next character.

So if you enter:

```
42
```

Then `Console.Read()` will return only `4` (as a character, which is 52 as an `int` if I'm not mistaken). The next invocation will then read `2`, which is 50 as an `int`. It basically reads the next character and interprets it as an integer.

So you should better stick with `Console.ReadLine()` if you want to read a whole line.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is reading a string and parsing it into an int. It will read all the info you type up until the `Enter`.

The second one is reading a `char`. Like Thomas said, note that if you type `123` and hit `Enter`, `Console.Read()` will take only `1` but if you have a subsequent `Console.Read()`, it'll take the `2` and then the `3`. So I doubt this is what you're trying to achieve.

If you try to calculate area by multiplying chars... it makes no sense.

I would recommend using :

```
int width = 0;
width = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out width);
```

Now width will be either zero, or a valid int.

And as the comment suggested, if you're looking for something like `24.5`, go for the `Double.TryParse`.